# CreateTopology fails Spatialite

Tags: spatialite

I wanted to experiment with the topology-geometry support that is available in [SpatiaLite 5.0.1](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html), but hitting a roadblock upon creating a topology. I am following the tutorial [Familiarizing with Topology-Geometry: an elementary tutorial](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=topo-start).

I executed the following commands:

```sh
$ rm -f test.sqlite
$ sqlite3 test.sqlite
sqlite> select load_extension('mod_spatialite');
sqlite> select spatialite_version();
5.0.1
sqlite> select HasTopology();
1
sqlite> SELECT CreateTopology('topotest', 4326, 0, 0); -- this call fails, not topology table is created
0
```

So according to the output my SpatiaLite installation has support for topology. Yet the `CreateTopology` call is failing, no topology table is created. Which is also indicated by the return value, see the [SpatiaLite docs](https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-5.0.1.html#topology).

Any idea's on troubleshooting the issue?

I am running on Ubuntu 21.10 with libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:5.0.1-2build1:

```sh
$ sudo apt-cache policy libsqlite3-mod-spatialite
libsqlite3-mod-spatialite:
  Installed: 5.0.1-2build1
  Candidate: 5.0.1-2build1
  Version table:
 *** 5.0.1-2build1 500
        500 http://nl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Comment: Do you get the same error with the command that is used in the tutorial `SELECT CreateTopology('topotest', 4326, 0, 0);`?

Comment: Good question; the result is the same. Will update the question with the commands from the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

I can only say that the command returns "1" and the topology tables are created with this spatialite-gui version on Windows.

[image]

Maybe you should send a question to Spatialite-users group https://groups.google.com/g/spatialite-users.